# Does a false statement always have a counterexample?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

It feels like a dumb question, but is it always the case that a false statement has a counterexample? Is there a proof of it (or of the contrapositive, if it has no counterexample it must be true)?

Comment: The statement $0=1$ has no counterexample in my opinion but is clearly False.

Comment: Does "counterexample" always make sense for any statement? For example, if "My name is Bill" is false, what exactly is a counterexample? One usually speaks of counterexamples for statements of the form "if A then B", so a counterexample would be a specific A and B for which the statement is false.

Comment: Only false universal statements (statements that assert that something occurs "for all" things) are suceptible to counterexamples.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's not quite true - or rather, universality (and counterexample-ness) isn't entirely clear-cut. For example, take a statement of the form "For some $x$, every $y$ makes $P(x,y)$ hold" (for some property $P$). This statement is false iff the statement "**for every function** $f$ (of appropriate type) there is some $x$ such that $\neg P(x, f(x))$ holds" is true. Via this translation, we can view such a function $f$ as a counterexample to the original statement. Moreover, this is nontrivial - e.g. it's often interesting to ask how complicated such an $f$ must be (if it exists).

Comment: Well, if its false there must be false.  I suppose we can wax philosophical as to what a "statement" and "example" mean.  I suppose "unicorns exist" doesn't have a counterexample because the true statement "there are no such things as unicorns" isn't a positive statement about things but an absence of a things.  Then again one could argue the universe itself, and the lack of unicorns,, therein is a counterexample.

Comment: To the OP: the conversion I described in my previous comment is a version of the (rather technical) process of [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form#How_Skolemization_works).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I'm going to disagree; if you have a statement "for every function $f$ `blah`", then of course any particular such function cannot prove the statement, so any particular such function cannot be a "counterexample" to the original statement, at least the way I understand the terms. Of course one can ask further questions about things, but that is hardly the same thing as producing "a counterexample". You cannot show that "There exists $x$ such that for every $y$, $P(x,y)$ holds" is false by producing an example... which is what a counterexample is supposed to be.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Now, if a statement $P$ is equivalent to a universal statement $Q$, then $P$ is susceptible to counterexamples via the equivalence because $Q$ is susceptible...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin " You cannot show that "There exists  such that for every $y$, $P(x,y)$ holds" is false by producing an example" Yes, you can - namely, you produce a function $f$ such that for each $x$ we have $\neg P(x,f(x))$. The existence of such a function $f$ is equivalent to the falsity of that statement. The statement "$\exists x\forall y(P(x,y))$" is equivalent to the universal, but higher type, statement "$\forall f\exists x(P(x,f(x)))$," and as a universal statement that does admit a counterexample (if false of course), albeit of higher type.

Comment: I was tempted to suggest that every false statement has a refutation - but of course this is not true because of Gödel - there are unprovable true statements, and their negations are therefore irrefutable false statements. For statements we know to be false, there is a reason we know them to be false: this may be a counterexample or a demonstration of incompatible properties, for example.

Comment: (Granted, the equivalence  right-to-left direction of that equivalence requires the axiom of choice ... :P)

Comment: @NoahSchweber We are talking at crosspurposes restricted by the limits of the comment setting. I would call "an example" to the existential statement a particular $x$ for which `blah`, rather than crafting an example to a separate (but equivalent) universal statement.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's fair, but I do believe that this is a subtlety worth mentioning, especially since it actually winds up leading in fruitful directions mathematically.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That, likewise, is fair.

Comment: A sense in which it is true is Gödel's completeness theorem : if a statement is "false" (in the sense of not being true ) then there is a universe (example) where it is really false

Comment: @Max: you should promote your comment to an answer: the naive concept "every false statement has a counterexample" is exactly what the completeness theorem captures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea of counterexample makes sense only for statements that claim that a certain property is held by all members of a given class of objects.

That is, if we have some false claim

> For all $m\in S,$ property $p$ holds,

then because it is false it is certain that there is at least some $m\in S$ for which $p$ fails to hold. There's not much more than this to prove. It follows immediately from the conditions.

Comment: The idea of a counterexample makes sense for any logical statement:  a counterexample is a structure in which the statement fails to hold. E.g., the integers provide a counterexample for the statement $\forall x.x + x = 0$ in the language of abelian groups.

Comment: @RobArthan I don't see how your example does not support my answer or buttresses your own point. As for your claim, what would you call a counterexample to the statement, $0=1,$ where $0,1\in\mathrm Z$?

Comment: The structure comprising the integers provides a counterexample.

Comment: @RobArthan That's a counterexample to the statement being *semantically true*. But we generally care about truth within some fixed context/model: e.g. when we say "$0=1$ is false" we don't mean "there is a structure not satisfying $0=1$," we mean "the standard model of arithmetic does not satisfy $0=1$." So I don't think that appropriately translates the question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I don't understand your comment: truth is a semantic concept so it is tautologous (in the English language sense of that term) to say "semantically true". What we mean when we say "$0 = 1$" is context-dependent: it is false in the context of integral domains as usually defined but neither true nor false in the context of rings. In the case of the theory of a specific structure like $\Bbb{N}$ in which $0 = 1$ fails to hold, that specific structure **is** the counter-example.

Comment: @RobArthan Most people would say that $9$ is a counterexample to "every odd number is prime." The counterexample-ness is taking place within a specified structure, it's not the structure itself but rather a configuration within it.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of my original comment, which was that the idea of a counterexample makes sense for any first-order statement while Allawonder's answer suggest that it only makes sense for statements of a certain form. The statement "all groups are commutative" is false and has counterexamples, but when expressed as a first-order statement in the language of group theory, it does not have the logical form $\forall m \in S . p(m)$.

Comment: @RobArthan I really have not been getting your point. I already said I meant $0=1$ in the context of the integers. This implies I don't mean anything outside. So how can the integers be a counterexample to $0=1$? It's simply false. It doesn't make sense to say that an *axiom* or a convention has a counterexample. That said, I was curious about your statement, *All groups are commutative,* and your claim that it's not of the proposed form. I wonder how not, since it's just a translation into symbols, nothing more, for all groups $G$ in the category of groups, $G$ is commutative.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about the context being the integers. However, the integers are manifestly a counterexample to $0 = 1$ as they comprise a structure for the language of a ring that includes constants named $0$ and $1$ in which $0 = 1$ fails to hold: that's what a counterexample to the assertion $0 = 1$ is.

Comment: @RobArthan Perhaps you need to check again. When I asked what the counterexample to the statement $0=1$ was, I *did* state that the symbols $0,1$ were to represent integers. Thus, it simply contradicts an axiom in the system $\mathrm Z.$ It is not a counterexample to anything within this system.

Comment: @Allawonder: I thought Ada asked the question, not you. It is unclear what "it" in your latest comment refers to or what you mean by "system" or by "anything within this system".

Comment: @RobArthan You may check, but Ada did not ask anything about $0=1$ or integers. I did in my first reply to your comment under my answer above (again, please check). By 'it' I meant the statement in question (namely $0=1$), and by system I meant the ring of integers.

Comment: @Allawonder: thanks for the clarifications, but I still don't understand why you don't consider the ring of integers to be a counterexample to the assertion that $0 = 1$.

Comment: @RobArthan For the same reason that I don't consider myself a counterexample to *I am a girl.*

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have indicated, this isn't a very clear question. The problem lies in what "false" means or what "example" in "counterexample" means or, possibly, what "statement" means? Or I should say what they mean to you.

As others have pointed out, it's not clear what a "counterexample" to a statement like $0=1$ should mean. Most likely, you really mean counterexamples to universal statements like $\forall x.P(x)$ (e.g. $\forall x.x = 0$). Now there's a question of what "example" and, relatedly, what "false" should mean.

Before I go into a more precise and technical perspective, I'll give a kind of "pragmatic" answer. Assuming you mean universal statements like the above, it is not the case that you will be able to *write down* an explicit counterexample even if you prove that the statement is "false", in the sense that you prove its negation.

Now for the various perspectives that arise from being precise. First, if we define "false" as the negation is provable, so $P$ is "false" iff $\vdash\neg P$ and we define "example" as a *term*, then the answer is "no". To be precise, we have a formula $\forall x.P(x)$ and we have $\vdash\neg\forall x.P(x)$. Classically, this is equivalent to $\vdash\exists x.\neg P(x)$, but, classically, it does not need to be the case that there exists a term, $t$, in our language such that $\vdash\neg P(t)$ even when we know $\vdash\exists x.\neg P(x)$. This is different for constructive logic where we have the [existence property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties#Existence_property) which guarantees that if we can prove a (closed) existential formula, then there is some term that witnesses it. However, the answer to your question is still "no" for constructive logic because $\neg\forall x.P(x)$ is not equivalent to $\exists x.\neg P(x)$ in constructive logic.

Round two. Let's define "false" as semantically false with respect to some model $\mathfrak M$. We then would talk about $\mathfrak M\vDash P$ which states that when we interpret the *closed* formula $P$ with respect to the model $\mathfrak M$, which I'll write as $[\![P]\!]_\mathfrak M$, then it is interpreted as a "true" value. In general, for an open formula $[\![P]\!]_\mathfrak M$ is the set of (tuples of) elements of the domain that satisfy the interperation of $P$. Given this, it is the case that if $\mathfrak M\vDash\neg \forall x.P(x)$, then there is an element, $c$, of the domain of $\mathfrak M$ such that $c\in[\![\neg P(x)]\!]_\mathfrak M$. To relate this to the first case, it may be the case that there exists no term $t$ such that $[\![t]\!]=c$. With this definition, the answer to your question is "yes" by the definition of the semantics of existential quantification.

Round three. If we define "false" to mean the negation is semantically valid, written $\vDash\neg P$ which is shorthand for $\mathfrak M\vDash\neg P$ for *all* models $\mathfrak M$, then we can talk about counter*models* which is basically a counterexample in the first sense of this meta-theoretic universal statement. That is, we find a model $\mathfrak M$ such that $\mathfrak M\vdash\neg P$ is false (in the sense of the second definition). Now $P$ doesn't itself need to be a universal statement. We can talk about countermodels to the formula $0=1$. This would be a model $\mathfrak M$ such that $[\![0]\!]_\mathfrak M\neq[\![1]\!]_\mathfrak M$. With this definition, the answer to your question is "no" but it's *almost* "yes". We do have a countermodel to $P$ when we know $\vDash\neg P$, any model will do, *except* if there are no models at all which will happen when your theory is inconsistent.

As a kind of Round two-and-a-half, we could consider defining "false" as $\nvDash P$ which states that $P$ isn't true in *every* model. It may be true in some but not others. The analysis of this just recapitulates the analysis we just did only at the meta-level. The meta-theory thinks that a countermodel exists in this case, but from a meta-meta-perspective whether we can write down a term to describe that countermodel is not given.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'counter-example' you mean a world in which the statement is false, then yes: it would be the very world (or situation or context) in which you evaluated the statement to be false.